# How to store a value in a dictionary permanently

Tags: python-2.7

I am building a sign-in program. However I am having problem saving the login details. I'm using a dictionary but it is not storing the value. When I open the file again there is no value in it. I'm new to python, but here's the code I have so far:

```
user={}
print'''
        \t1)NEW USER
        2)\tEXISTING USER'''
f=input("ENTER ANY OF THE ABOVE OPTIONS-")
def check():
    user={}
    new=raw_input("PLEASE ENTER YOUR USERNAME:-")
    pas=raw_input("PLEASE ENTER YOUR PASSWORD:-")
    if user[new]==pas:
        return True
        print "Log In Successful!!"
    else:
        print"Invalid Entry!"
        return False
def newuser():
    user={}
    new=raw_input("ENTER YOUR USER ID :-")
    pas=raw_input("ENTER YOUR PASSWORD :-")
    user[new]=pas
    print "new user added"

if f==1:
    check()
if f==2:
    newuser()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, whenever you run the program again all of your variables all cleared, its a brand new environment. You have two options:

1. Use a database, you can use sqlite for a small application. Check the sqlite drive documentation for python. https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html
2. You can write your values to a file. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files. Instead of saving this in a dictionary you can write the values to a file and everytime you run your program again you can just retrieve them.

This is a problem of persistence. Data structures by itself do not persist data after a session is over, you need to write it in other place and write it back to a data structure if you the functionality you want.

Comment: Any comments on this?